# Cannot import file from same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Trying to import a file (`meleeWeapons.py`) into my main file (`main.py`) but it does not seem to be working.

The file directy is as follows

```
Domination
  |_main.py
  |_meleeWeapons.py
  |_test.py
```

When I load `from Domination import meleeWeapons` or `from . import meleeWeapons` into main.py, trying to load any objects from meleeWeapons into main doesnt work, flagging `"myObject" is not defined`. When I do the `from Domination import meleeWeapons` approach, the error "Import "Dominations" could not be resolved"

Comment: If your using it in `main.py` does simple `import meleeWeapons` work?

Comment: @sammy No, it does not

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
When I use `import <local file>` in my own structure, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import things from a local module, you put the module name **first**, then the symbols ("objects") **second**

```py
from meleeWeapons import Domination
```

If you want to import everything into the global namespace (you *rarely*, if ever, want to do this), then do this:

```py
from meleeWeapons import *
```

If you want import the module itself, and using `meleeWeapons.Dominion` to access `Dominion` (or any other symbol), then just do a standard import:

```py
import meleeWeapons
```

You can also give the module an alias:

```py
import meleeWeapons as mW
```

Comment: This does not work, but the import doesnt flag errors. Still, no objects are getting imported from `meleeWeapons.py` to `main.py`

Comment: What do you mean by `no objects are getting imported from ...`? Have you tried using the variables exported from `meleeWeapons.py`?

Comment: The `from meleeWeapons import *` worked. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You're using the wrong syntax.  You need

```
import meleeWeapons
```

What you did was to tell Python to look in the file Domination.py, and return the symbol meleeWeapons.

Comment: This does not work, but the import doesnt flag errors. Still, no objects are getting imported from `meleeWeapons.py` to `main.py`

Comment: @goose.mp4 the objects (functions, variables, classes, etc) would have to be accessed by using `meleeWeapons.OBJECT`